# Names of variables inside the 'for loop'

Tags: r, dataset, formula

In **my_data** I want to create new variables. I do not know how to give names to my new variables, taking into account that those new variables are inside the for loop.

```
for (i in 2:ncol(my_data)) {
sdev <- sd(my_data[,i])
my_data$colnames(my_data[i]) <- my_data[,i]/sd(my_data[,i])
}
```

I tried this way, but it doesn't work. There should be **i** new variables, and every variable should have different name.
Thanks!

Comment: You can do this with `[[ ... ]]`

`my_data[[colname_string]] <- code`

Comment: It does not work, or I wrote the wrong code. Can you write a whole code?

Comment: Something like this https://gist.github.com/DexGroves/f2a65e69b2bc8048e63a774b611bf646

Comment: This seems more fitting for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you Dex very much!